# OpenGL ES20 - Light a cube, how to get normals?

Tags: android, matrix, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, normals

To add some lightning to my OpenGL ES20 cube, I need to calculate the normals for each plane. I've found a "tutorial" on lightning, but they simply hard-coded the normals into the cube, which appears to me as not the best option, since it seems limited?

So my approach to the cube is as follows:

```
private float[] mVertices = {
        -1, -1, -1, // bottom left
        1, -1, -1, // bottom right   back
        1, 1, -1, // top right
        -1, 1, -1, // top left
        -1, -1, 1, // bottom left
        1, -1, 1, // bottom right   front
        1, 1, 1, // top right
        -1, 1, 1 // top left
};

private float[] mColors = {
        0.6f, 0f, 0.6f,
        0.6f, 0f, 0.6f,
        0.6f, 0f, 0.6f,
        0.6f, 0f, 0.6f,

        0.8f, 0f, 0.6f,
        0.8f, 0f, 0.6f,
        0.8f, 0f, 0.6f,
        0.8f, 0f, 0.6f
};

private float[] mNormal = new float[?]; ?

private short[] mIndices = {
        0, 4, 5,
        0, 5, 1,

        1, 5, 6,
        1, 6, 2,

        2, 6, 7,
        2, 7, 3,

        3, 7, 4,
        3, 4, 0,

        4, 7, 6,
        4, 6, 5,

        3, 0, 1,
        3, 1, 2
};
```

i.e. i have all 8 vertices defined as well as indices, on how to combine them to triangles.
To get the normal matrix, I've read that I am supposed to invert the matrix, then transpose it. So I've tried this:

```
    float[] mTempMatrix = new float[mVertices.length];
    Matrix.invertM(mTempMatrix, 0, mVertices, 0);
    Matrix.transposeM(mNormal, 0, mTempMatrix, 0);
```

But this is always filled with zeros, and my cube stays black. How example am I supposed to calculate the normal matrix? Should it be something with the model matrix? If yes, where am I supposed to do this, since the only place they are really combined is in the shader? Is there another way to do this which would be more appropriate?

Comment: Your vertices are hardcoded so it makes sense to hardcode the normals too (they aren't going to change any more than the vertices are). In what manner do you see that as presenting a limitation of some sort?

Comment: Mh yes that's true, I was thinking the other way since I'm changing the vertices in the constructor - but I'm only shifting them according to width, height and depth of the cube. I was more thinking into "the future", for more detailled and complex objects, like polygons etc. Also I'm kind of confused how I would add the normals hardcoded the way it is right now, especially with the indices, how many I would need and where they should be based upon? EDIT: In the examples I've seen, they had a lot more vertices defined, without indices, thats why I can't really see how I should adapt that part.

Comment: Ok, I've been trying some stuff. I think to "hardcode" the normals in it, I have to change the way the cube is drawn. I've changed the colors, to determine which index is which side of the cube, but changing all colors to white except for one resulted in a colored corner, sinde the vertex is used more than once. So I don't really know how I am supposed to add a plane normal in my cube's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that you share vertices between cube faces. The normal is a vector that points othogonal to the plane of the surface.

Consider the top/right/front vertex as an example (that you share with the front, right and top faces).

When used on the front face, the normal needs to point towards you as 0, 0, 1
When used on the right face, the normal needs to point to the right as 1, 0, 0
When used on the top face, the normal needs to point up as 0, 1, 0

So how to reconcile that?
You could set the normal for the vertex to point out from the corner, e.g. as 0.707, 0.707, 0.707. That'll most likely give you an interesting lighting effect on the corner but is probably not what you're after.

The other solution is not to re-use the vertices between faces. So you'll need 24 (4 per side) instead of 8. You'll then have 3 versions of each vertex but each one of those now belongs to just one face, hence you can set the normal vector as perpendicular to that face. You'll also be able to set the color for just that face as well since you'll no longer be sharing the vertex with other faces.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Thought there would be a convenient solution with the indices and not re-writing vertices that often, but I've now switched over to having the same vertices more often, and now I can finally see some light.