# Understanding indices in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I know there are a lot of questions regarding indices, but none of them solve my problem. I am trying to get a model loaded with diffuse light source into openGl ES and rotate it. I first started with a 3D cube and managed to rotate it. Then i added a light source. That also went without a glitch. Now i'm trying to load a model from it's .obj file and rotate it in place of the cube. I tried two .obj converters but it didn't do the trick for me. Then i created my own .obj importer and the result was the same. I get a distorted image (the lighting and rotation still work on the distorted model). Now i feel that my knowledge about indices might be incomplete.

What I am doing is i am creating a vertexPositionArray[] to store the vertex information and a vertexNormalArray[] to store the corresponding normals with a 1:1 ratio. Now i create an indexArray which stores the order in which the position and the normals should be called.
For eg. if i pass in 3, 5, 6, I am referring to the 3rd, 5th, 6th positions in the vertexPositionArray[] and vertexNormalArray[] both or just the vertexPositionArray?

[This is a model that i want to use in my project, and on the sides are the output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik4Kf.jpg)

Here is a piece of code that i used to extract the info i wanted from .obj file:

```
 String[] vData={"-1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f,",
                "1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f,",
                "-1.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f,",
                "1.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f,",
                "0.513184f, 0.000000f, 0.513184f,",
                "0.513184f, 0.000000f, -0.513184f,",
                "-0.513184f, 0.000000f, -0.513184f,",
                "-0.513184f, 0.000000f, 0.513184f,",
                "0.158195f, 0.690612f, 0.158195f,",
                "0.158195f, 0.690612f, -0.158195f,",
                "-0.158195f, 0.690612f, -0.158195f,",
                 "-0.158195f, 0.690612f, 0.158195f,"};

String[] nData={"-0.889400f, 0.457200f, 0.000000f,",
                "0.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f,",
                "0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f,",
                "0.889400f, 0.457200f, 0.000000f,",
                "0.000000f, 0.457200f, 0.889400f,",
                "0.000000f, 0.457200f, -0.889400f,"};
int[] vOrder={8, 12, 11,
            6, 5, 3,
            7, 6, 1,
            8, 7, 2,
            5, 8, 4,
            11, 12, 9,
            6, 10, 9,
            5, 9, 12,
            7, 11, 10,
            7, 8, 11,
            1, 6, 3,
            2, 7, 1,
            4, 8, 2,
            3, 5, 4,
            10, 11, 9,
            5, 6, 9,
            8, 5, 12,
            6, 7, 10};

int[] nOrder={ 1, 1, 1,
             2, 2, 2,
             2, 2, 2,
             2, 2, 2,
             2, 2, 2,
             3, 3, 3,
             4, 4, 4,
             5, 5, 5,
             6, 6, 6,
             1, 1, 1,
             3, 3, 3,
             3, 3, 3,
             3, 3, 3,
             3, 3, 3,
             3, 3, 3,
             4, 4, 4,
             5, 5, 5,
             6, 6, 6,
};

FileWriter write = new FileWriter( path , false);
PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter( write );

print_line.println("float[] vertexData ={");
for(int i=0;i<vOrder.length;i++)
{
    print_line.println(vData[vOrder[i]-1]);
    vCount++;
}
print_line.println("};");


print_line.println("float[] vertexNormal ={");
for(int i=0;i<nOrder.length;i++)
{
    print_line.println(nData[nOrder[i]-1]);
}
print_line.println("};");

print_line.println("Vertex Count = "+vCount);

print_line.close();
}    
}
```

I got vData (vertex) and nData (normals) from the obj file by using the replace function in a text editor. Similarly i got the vOrder and nOrder by the data on the faces given below (Adding the number before'//' to vOrder and the one after to nOrder):

```
f 8//1 12//1 11//1
f 6//2 5//2 3//2
f 7//2 6//2 1//2
f 8//2 7//2 2//2
f 5//2 8//2 4//2
f 11//3 12//3 9//3
f 6//4 10//4 9//4
f 5//5 9//5 12//5
f 7//6 11//6 10//6
f 7//1 8//1 11//1
f 1//3 6//3 3//3
f 2//3 7//3 1//3
f 4//3 8//3 2//3
f 3//3 5//3 4//3
f 10//3 11//3 9//3
f 5//4 6//4 9//4
f 8//5 5//5 12//5
f 6//6 7//6 10//6
```

Could anyone please tell me what is it I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if i pass in 3, 5, 6, I am referring to the 3rd, 5th, 6th positions in the vertexPositionArray[] and vertexNormalArray[] both or just the vertexPositionArray?
**Both**

Do i need to bind my position and normal arrays into 1 array?
**No**, but you can, not required.

tell me if i understand the .obj file correctly:- f 8//1 5//4 6//3 for this i pushed the vertexPositionArray[7] and vertexNormalArray[0] into a new vertexPArray[] and vertexNArray[], respectively.

**Yes, because Obj files're not related to OpenGL at all.**

In OpenGL, you can have only one indices array but OBJ files, you can have three types of inces (f v1/vt1/vn1 v2/vt2/vn2 v3/vt3/vn3 ....) so you should create your new vertexPArray[] and vertexNArray[] using the faces data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At least now i know i'm going on the right path. I have changed my question to include a basic java code. Could please take a look at it and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user3505839 you should make new vertice arrary and normal array using vOrder & nOrder. If you take a look at 6th vertice in (6, 5, 3) and 6th vertice
            (7, 6, 1) both of them have a same position which is "0.513184f, 0.000000f, -0.513184f," so you need a new indices array too stead of vOrder. If you don't get it ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603612/opengl-es20-light-a-cube-how-to-get-normals

Comment: I realised that since I'm rearranging the vertex points and the corresponding normals by using vOrder and nOrder respectively, I needed a new index array. But would not the new index array be {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5......54, 55}

Comment: @user3505839 no, the new array will be more like vOrder but 8, 12, 11,
            6, 5, 3,
            7, 13, 1,
            14, 15, 2,
            16, 17, 4...  any vertex must not be overlapped since there is no normal value overlapped